# await inside async controller function

Tags: node.js

Node noob here, I wish to create a pbkdf2 key with node. Though I cannot seem to get a string back after `crypto.pbkdf2` has been run. The key returns in the callback ok, though not sure how to deal with using this in the code after.

I'm calling a controller function as follows:

```
exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {

  let key;
  await crypto.pbkdf2('secret', 'salt', 100000, 64, 'sha512', (err, derivedKey) => {
    if (err){
      console.log(err)
      console.log('err')
    }
    key = derivedKey.toString('hex')
    console.log('callback'+key)
  })

  console.log('post-await'+key)

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks

Comment: `await` requires an expression which returns a `Promise`. If you want to keep it async, you need to wrap `crypto.pbkdf2` in a `Promise`. Otherwise, you could use `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` and remove the `await`.

Comment: As jcaron said, you use `await` only to await a promise.  It does not work with any arbitrary asynchronous operation.  There is no magic sauce in `await` that somehow knows when an async operation is done.  It ONLY knows how to wait for a promise to be resolved.  So, if you do `await fn()` and `fn()` is an asynchronous operation, then `fn()` HAS to return a promise for `await` to work properly.  In this particular case, I don't see any meaningful advantage to using `await` since you have only a single async operation.

Comment: @jfriend00 the issue seems to be that without awaiting, I cannot access the result further down the code. `const pbkdf2 = crypto.pbkdf2...` then logging after it returns undefined.

Comment: Code further down just needs to be INSIDE the callback.